# Python: Zip all files individually in a folder

Tags: python, json, csv, zip

I have been trying to find out answer but nothing specific to my situation. I am very new to programming.
I have 20-30 .csv files in a folder.
I would like to loop through all files, and zip each csv file into .zip file (different folder)

```
C:\users\xyz\Source\NumberOne.csv
C:\users\xyz\Source\NumberTwo.csv
C:\users\xyz\Source\NumberThree.csv


C:\users\xyz\Dest\NumberOne.zip
C:\users\xyz\Dest\NumberTwo.zip
C:\users\xyz\Dest\NumberThree.zip
```

i have tried different code functions from internet, but nothing works on individual files. the working code i have, zips all files into 1 zip folder.

please help

Comment: Do you know how to create a zip archive for a single file? Do you know how to get a list of `*.csv` files in a given directory? Do you know how to use a `for`-loop? If you don't know the answer to any of these questions then ask a separate question for each specific issue

Answer (score 3):

This should work. You need to pass in the source and destination directories when running it (or modify the code).

```
import os
import sys
import zipfile


def csv_files(source_dir):
    for filename in os.listdir(source_dir):
        if filename.endswith('.csv'):
            yield filename


source_dir = sys.argv[1]  # r'C:\users\xyz\Source\'
dest_dir = sys.argv[2]  # r'C:\users\xyz\Dest\'

os.chdir(source_dir)  # To work around zipfile limitations

for csv_filename in csv_files(source_dir):
    file_root = os.path.splitext(csv_filename)[0]
    zip_file_name = file_root + '.zip'
    zip_file_path = os.path.join(dest_dir, zip_file_name)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_path, mode='w') as zf:
        zf.write(csv_filename)
```

Comment: Most excellent.
I would add:
```from os.path import basename```
```zf.write(filename,basename(filename))```
so it will not have the long path when extracting

Answer (score 0):

To zip a file you can use this:

```
import commands

cmd = 'zip -j ' + zipfile + ' ' + file 
commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

Comment: Python has the `zipfile` module; no need to run an external command.

Answer (score 0):

To save all `.csv` files from a source folder as individual `.zip` archives in a destination folder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile

src_dir, dest_dir = map(Path, sys.argv[1:])
for filename in src_dir.glob('*.csv'): # enumerate all csv-files in the src folder
    # zip each file individually
    with ZipFile(str(dest_dir / (filename.stem + '.zip')), 'w') as archive:
        archive.write(str(filename), arcname=filename.name)
```

Example:

```
T:\> py zip-csv-files.py C:\users\xyz\Source C:\users\xyz\Dest
```